# Net::SSH2 hangs at creating new object, after upgrading server to SLES 11 SP3

Tags: perl, sles

My software was running fine with SUSE Enterprise Linux 11 SP2, but I had to upgrade to SP3. After upgrading my Net::SSH2 based Perl modules are just hanging without giving any error and not even getting timeout. So, I created a simple test script with Net::SSH2 which runs successfully in SP2 machines, but not in SP3. Here is the test script

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use Net::SSH2;

my ($host, $user, $password) = ("myhost", "myuser", "mypassword");

print "Before Net::SSH2-new()\n";
my $ssh = Net::SSH2->new();

print "Before ssh->Connect\n";
$ssh->connect($host);

print "Before ssh->auth_keyboard\n";
$ssh->auth_keyboard($user, $password);

print "Before ssh->Channel\n";
my $channel = $ssh->channel();

print "Before Channel->blocking(0)\n";    
$channel->blocking(0);

print "Before Channel->exec\n";    
my $rt = $channel->exec("hostname");
print "The return value is: $rt \n";

#Closing connection
$channel->close;
$ssh->disconnect;
```

In SP3 server I am getting output as follows

```
myuser@myhost:~> perl  test_ssh  
Before Net::SSH2-new()
```

And then nothing. But in SP2 servers, it is working without any problem. Can someone tell what is causing this problem?

Comment: Do you have access to a machine on both SP2 and SP3 -- can you run the following two commands on both and share the output. `perl -V | head -1` and `perl -e 'use Net::SSH2; say $Net::SSH2::VERSION . "\n"'`

Comment: I just looked at the release notes for SLES 11 SP3.  Apparently it includes an update to openssh.  As Net::SSH2 is an XS module, you will probably need to recompile it.

Comment: Net::SSH2 is buggy and the underneath libssh2 is even more buggy. Anyway, how have you installed libssh2? and Net::SSH2? SLES does not guarantees binary compatibility between releases, so anything compiled by you (i.e. not an rpm) may bump on new library versions.